# java find a list element by its class

Tags: java, list, java-7

i'm using soot to analyse Java-Code. Because Soot still got no full Java 8-Support im working with Java 7.
I need to get the first element of the class LinkedRValueBox.

My actual list looks like this:

> [ImmediateBox(0), ImmediateBox(1), LinkedRValueBox(0 + 1)]

Of course i could iterate the list and proof every Element with `instanceof`.
I couldn't find any solution for this issue.

Comment: you already have your solution id say

Comment: If you're on Java 7 you have no choice but to use an imperative approach to this, which you already have figured out. You can also compare the item's class with the desired class, which *might* perform better than using `instanceof`.

Comment: Usually if you need to use `instanceof`, you have an wrong OOP design.

Comment: @m0skit0 Maybe. But not always.

Comment: @GhostCat **Usually**

Comment: i agree with your arguments. But i think soot has a very good structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a third-party library, with [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) version `7.x`, you can either use `detect` with `Predicates.instanceOf()` or if you want to filter the list, can use `selectInstancesOf()`.  Here's an example which uses different types of `Number`, and detects the first instance of `Double`.

```
MutableList<? extends Number> list =
        Lists.mutable.with(new Integer(0), new Long(0), new Double(0));
Number detect = list.detect(Predicates.instanceOf(Double.class));
MutableList<Double> doubles = list.selectInstancesOf(Double.class);
Double first = doubles.getFirst();
Assert.assertTrue(detect instanceof Double);
Assert.assertSame(detect, first);
```

Eclipse Collection version `8.x` compiles using Java 8, but version `7.x` works with Java 5 or greater.

Note: I am a committer for [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

Comment: ty, i'll have a look at it